# Rhino Mocks 'Expect' with FakeItEasy

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, fakeiteasy

I have a database manipulating object as a dependency of my UUT (Unit Under Test). Therefore, I want to make it as a strict mock, because I also want to make sure that the UUT does not call any other methods that can result db change.

In rhino mocks I did the following:

1. I made a strictmock from the db object
2. I made an .Expect clause in Arrange
3. I called VerifyAllExpectations in Assert

However, when I want to do this in FakeItEasy, I can't find how to do it without code duplication. I tried putting the CallsTo()+MustHaveHappened() parts in the Arrange, but then my test fail. If I put the CallsTo()+MustHaveHappened() parts in the Assert, then my test fail also, because unexpected calls were made to a strict fake. Can this be done without putting the CallsTo call into both Arrange and Assert?

Comment: UUT = Unit Under Test?

Comment: Yes, UUT = Unit Under Test

Comment: I see, thanks. I hadn't heard that term before. I usually use SUT - System Under Test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that with following verifications:

```
var service = A.Fake<IService>();

testedObject.CallService("data");

// verify your specific call to .PostData
A.CallTo(() => service.PostData("data")).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
// verify that no more than 1 call was made to fake object
A.CallTo(service).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

The `A.CallTo(object)` overload allows you to make a generic setup/verification on *all and any* of the fake object methods.

Comment: +1 this works. FYI I've polled the FIE owners to find out if there is a more elegant way to solve this https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/198

Comment: And I answered @AdamRalph with a "why not just suck the `() => service.PostData…)` into a variable and use it in the Arrange and Assert? It's still two calls, as in this answer, but (I think) slightly more idiomatic FIE.

Answer (score 6):

Whilst the answer from @jimmy_keen will work (I even upvoted it) a more idiomatic use of FakeItEasy would be:

```
// Arrange
var service = A.Fake<IService>(o => o.Strict()); // only allows configured calls
A.CallTo(() => service.PostData("data")).DoesNothing(); // allow a specific call

// Act
testedObject.CallService("data");

// Assert
A.CallTo(() => service.PostData("data")).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

--- UPDATE ---

With help from @blairconrad over at https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/198#issuecomment-29145440 I think this is the neatest way to do this, without duplication:

```
// Arrange
var service = A.Fake<IService>(o => o.Strict()); // only allows configured calls
var expectedCall = A.CallTo(() => service.PostData("data"));
expectedCall.DoesNothing(); // allow the call

// Act
testedObject.CallService("data");

// Assert
expectedCall.MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

Comment: "Can this be done without putting the CallsTo call into both Arrange and Assert?"
I knew this version and my question was exactly about avoiding this.

Comment: You have a point about the code duplication. Currently there's no way to achieve this with a strict fake without code duplication. I've re-opened the issue at FakeItEasy to discuss further https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/198#issuecomment-29138957

Comment: Wow, so the CallTo returns a "call object" that can be verified later on. Interesting, upvoted.

Comment: Yeah, it's FakeItEasy. It's easy. ;-)